# How to merge three diff columns in a single column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have three columns from different tables:

```
SELECT
    t1.Count_1, t2.Count_2, t3.Count_3 
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count_1 FROM GuestAddressData) AS t1, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count_2 FROM GuestAddressData) AS t2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count_3 FROM SMSTable) AS t3
```

But now I want to get it like:

```
1,1,1 as total
```

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Concat the results? e.g.. `select t1.Count_1 + ',' + t2.Count_2 + ',' + t3.Count_3 [total]`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  2008

Comment: 2008 what? SSMS?

Comment: do you want sum of these in total or there values comma separated?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle SQL, you could use:

```
t1.Count_1||','||t2.Count_2||','||t3.Count_3 as total
```

For SQL Server you could use:

```
CAST(t1.Count_1 AS varchar) + ',' + CAST(t2.Count_2 AS varchar) + ',' + CAST(t3.Count_3 AS varchar) as total
```

Comment: error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int.

Comment: @aparnarai for SQL Server, try the edited line of code